# Background image is shown interrupted because of other elements

Tags: html, css

My background is interrupted by the list and by the `h3` but it has to be one solid line. The yellow thing is a background image. Pleas need help. Is for a school project.

In the image you see a yellow driangle dis ist the interrupted image:

[image: In the image you see a yellow driangle dis ist the interrupted image]

This is my code:

```css
* {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300x300/");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42pt;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300x300/f00/fff");
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28pt;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
  color: yellow;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Jonas Ploberger">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Übersicht jonas Ploberger</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="startseite.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PlobergerJonas</h1>
  <h3>Home</h3>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="startseite.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="photoshop.html">PS Bilder</a></li>
    <li><a href="ausbildung.html">Ausbildung</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
* {
      background-image: url("https://placehold.it/300x300/");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-color: #252525;
      color: white;
      font-family: arial;
  }
```

you are using the universal selector '*' and so you are setting a background image to every element in your html document.

So you want to replace that selector with either 'body' or any other element you want to have that background image on.